# Optimize Julia Code by Example

Tags: performance, optimization, julia, numerical-methods

I am currently writing a numerical solver in Julia. I don't think the math behind it matters too much. It all boils down to the fact, that a specific operation is executed several times and uses a large percentage (~80%) of running time.

I tried to reduce it as much as possible and present you this piece of code, which can be saved as `dummy.jl` and then executed via `include("dummy.jl")` followed by `dummy(10)` (for compilation) and then `dummy(1000)`.

```
function dummy(N::Int64)
    A = rand(N,N)
    @time timethis(A)
end

function timethis(A::Array{Float64,2})
    dummyvariable = 0.0
    for k=1:100 # just repeat a few times
        for i=2:size(A)[1]-1
            for j=2:size(A)[2]-1
                    dummyvariable += slopefit(A[i-1,j],A[i,j],A[i+1,j],2.0)
                    dummyvariable += slopefit(A[i,j-1],A[i,j],A[i,j+1],2.0)
            end
        end
    end
    println(dummyvariable) 
end

@inline function minmod(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    return sign(x) * max(0.0, min(abs(x),y*sign(x) ) );
end

@inline function slopefit(left::Float64,center::Float64,right::Float64,theta::Float64)
    # arg=ccall((:minmod,"libminmod"),Float64,(Float64,Float64),0.5*(right-left),theta*(center-left));
    # result=ccall((:minmod,"libminmod"),Float64,(Float64,Float64),theta*(right-center),arg);
    # return result

    tmp = minmod(0.5*(right-left),theta*(center-left));
    return minmod(theta*(right-center),tmp);
    #return 1.0
end
```

Here, `timethis` shall imitate the part of the code where I spend a lot of time. I notice, that `slopefit`is extremely expensive to execute.

For example, `dummy(1000)` takes roughly 4 seconds on my machine. If instead, `slopefit` would just always return `1` and not compute anything, the time goes down to one tenth of the overall time.

Now, obviously there is no free lunch.

I am aware, that this is simply a costly operation. But I would still try to optimize it as much as possible, given that a lot of time is spend in something that looks like one could optimize it easily as it is just a few lines of code.

So far, I tried to implement `minmod` and `slopefit` as C-functions and call them, however that just increased computing time (maybe I did it wrong).

So my question is, what possibilities do I have to optimize the call of `slopefit`?

Note, that in the actual code, the arguments of `slopefit` are not the ones mentioned here, but depend on conditional statements which makes everything hard to vectorize (if that would bring any performance gain I am not sure).

Comment: Adding `@inbounds` to the two inner `for` loops in `timethis()` reduces the run time a little bit for me. Something curious, though, is that `@code_native minmod(1.0,1.0)` produces much more code than I would naively expect (but I'm far from an expert). Maybe there's a missed optimization somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two levels of optimization I can think of.

First: the following implementation of `minmod` will be faster as it avoids branching (I understand this is the functionality you want):

```
@inline minmod(x::Float64, y::Float64) = ifelse(x<0, clamp(y, x, 0.0), clamp(y, 0.0, x))
```

Second: you can use `@inbounds` to speed up loop a bit:

```
 @inbounds for i=2:size(A)[1]-1
```

Comment: While the `@inbounds` idea did not do much to the overall timing, the new `minmod` was able to reduce the runtime of the actual code from `118sec` to `66sec`, which is aweseome! Hoping that someone might come up with further tricks, I would wait another day or two to accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, regarding `@inbounds` that is why I have said "a bit" :).

Comment: Sidenote, use `size(A, 1)` instead of `size(A)[1]`, etc.